# read one by one array value where clause

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Here's my controller

```
$data['lvl0'] = $this->web_model->menulvl0();
if ($data['lvl0'] != ''){
  foreach($data['lvl0'] as $l0){
     $data['id'] = $l0['id'];
 $data['name'] = $l0['name'];
 $temp = explode(" ",$l0['id']);
 $data['lvl1'] = $this->web_model->menulvl1($temp);
 }
}
```

when i print_r($temp). the result is :

```
Array ( [0] => 10 ) 
Array ( [0] => 20 ) 
Array ( [0] => 30 ) 
Array ( [0] => 40 )
```

I want to put that array into query. here's my query :

`SELECT id, name FROM A where level = 1 and parent = '$array'`

I want that array are read one by one. So, query will be:

`SELECT id, name FROM A where level = 1 and parent = '10'`

and then

`SELECT id, name FROM A where level = 1 and parent = '20'`

and so on.

How can do that?

Comment: $temp = explode(" ",$data['id']); this is correct statement I suppose your index of array should change just select the ids and then just where in that $temp array of ids you would avoid querying in for each it's very bad habit!!!

Comment: @saurabh2836 $data['id'] only holds $l0['id'], if I put  $l0['id'] on $temp. I think it doesnt matter and it doesnt even resolve my problem.

Comment: Then there is no need for that $data[id] use that $temp array in the where Id in $temp array in MySQL it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach statement to sort through your array:

```
foreach($array as $val)
{
    $query="SELECT id, name FROM A where level = 1 and parent = '".$val."'";
}
```

You can either run it in there, or just make the queries.

Alternately you can use an [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and an `in` statement:

```
$vals=implode(",",$array);
$query="SELECT id, name FROM A where level = 1 and parent in(".$vals.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using [**CI's active record**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
$query=$this->db->select('id, name')
->from('A')
->where('level',1)
->where_in('parent',$array)
->order_by('parent')
->get();

$result=$query->result();
```